# Command line podcatcher with per-podcast automatic/nonautomatic download

Tags: command-line, multimedia, podcast

Is there a command line podcatcher that lets me configure some podcasts to be downloaded automatically and asks before downloading if other podcasts where updated depending on the configuration for each podcast?

Answer (score 2):

I use `hpodder` (`sudo apt-get install hpodder;man hpodder`). It lets me automate my downloads, I can set podcasts to be excluded from auto-download, I can set the status of individual podcast episodes so that they will or won't be downloaded. I run `hpodder` at night, when my mp3 player is plugged in to recharge. A command I use after subscribing to an existing podcast, with say, 1000 episodes, and I want to skip the first 995:

```
hpodder setstatus --status=Skipped --castid=82 $( seq 1 995 )
```